# Update Managed metadata column using REST API in Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, flow, power-automate

How can we update managed metadata column in SharePoint using REST API in Power Automate?

Answer (score 2):

Before updating, you will first need to get the GUID of required term.
A simple request will be like below:

[image]

```
‘__metadata’: {   

    ‘type’: ‘SP.Data.YourListTitleListItem’   

},   

“TermFieldName”:{ 

    “Label”:”Test Value 1″, 

    “TermGuid”:”GUID of the Term”, 

    “WssId”:-1 //which make sure to create an entry in TaxonomyHiddenList if not added. 

    }
```

Comment: how to update if managed metadata  is multiple select ?

Comment: dude, this WssId = -1 creates a new entry on TaxonomyHiddenList is the real gold here.  I don't find this documented anywhere but this works!   For my use case we have a list which has a reference column to a managed metadata field, and the REST API requires an entry on TaxonomyHiddenList for the updates/inserts to our list work right.  Could not figure out how to add to the hidden list programmatically, but this works!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Send an HTTP request to SharePoint` with the below API

```
/_api/web/lists('Libray-List Name')/Items(ItemID)
```

[image]

> **Ref:** [Updating a row with METADATA FIELD in Rest API](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Updating-a-row-with-METADATA-FIELD-in-Rest-API/td-p/353389)
>
> Also, this [guide](http://www.cleverworkarounds.com/2017/10/20/powerapps-flow-and-managed-metadata-fields-part-3/) would help you to understand and work with
> Automate and Managed Metadata fields

**Read more at**

- [Update managed metadata column using term label or GUID](https://plumsail.com/docs/actions/v1.x/flow/how-tos/sharepoint/update-sp-item.html)
- [Updating A Managed Metadata (MMS) Column Dynamically In A SharePoint List Using MS Flow](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/updating-an-managed-metadata-mms-column-dynamically-in-a-sharepoint-list-using/)

Comment: i  tired below  test is success but its not updating even in version history it show my name but no updates {
"__metadata": {"type": "SP.Data.ControlDocumentsItem"},
"Published": 'Yes',
"ApprovalStatus":'Publish',
"Title":'@{items('Apply_to_each_2')['Title']}',
"Business": { "__metadata": {"type":"SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue"},
"TermGuid":'@{items('Apply_to_each_2')['Business']['TermGuid']}',
"Label":'@{items('Apply_to_each_2')['Business']['Label']}',
"WssId":'-1'
}

}

Answer (score 0):

If you have a GUID of managed metadata term then you can use SharePoint REST API to update managed metadata column in SharePoint using Power Automate.

Check below articles for detailed steps:

1. [Updating A Managed Metadata (MMS) Column Dynamically In A SharePoint List Using MS Flow](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/updating-an-managed-metadata-mms-column-dynamically-in-a-sharepoint-list-using/)
2. [Microsoft Flow: update Managed Metadata Column of a Document Set](https://knowhere365.space/microsoft-flow-update-managed-metadata-column-of-a-document-set/)
3. [Microsoft Flow: update Multi value Managed Metadata Column of a Document Set](https://knowhere365.space/microsoft-flow-update-multi-value-managed-metadata-column-of-a-document-set/) - If you have multiple selection enabled